# Applying a loop to a function in R

Tags: r

Good day,

I have managed to write a script to normalize data in a row using the row's mean. I am not sure if I used the function command to create a suitable function (code)

```
hyp <- function(x){
 andira<-subset(filenames, select=c(Wavelength,X400:X2400))
 myBreaks <- gl(ceiling((ncol(andira)-1)/5), 5)[1:(ncol(andira)-1)]
 and.mean<-cbind(andira[1],
       sapply(levels(myBreaks), function(y) {
         rowMeans(andira[-1][myBreaks == y])
       }))
 library(data.table)
 and.T <- as.data.table(and.mean)
 and.T.new<-and.T[,list(Mean=rowMeans(.SD)), by=Wavelength]
 normalized<-and.mean/and.T.new$Mean
 normalized$Wavelength<-andira$Wavelength
 final<-aggregate(normalized, by=list(normalized$Wavelength), FUN=mean)
    write.table(final, file = "data-appended.csv", sep = ",",
             col.names = FALSE, append=TRUE)
}
```

I would like to have this function applied to different files I have saved in a folder. I have searched and seen that I can read all the files placed in the folder (Functions) by using this command:

```
filenames <- list.files("C:/Users/dfs/Documents/Function", pattern="*.txt",       full.names=TRUE)
```

I figure I may have to use a loop, but I have never used one before and I am not sure how to implement the loop to ensure the script is automatically applied to all the files and the end result is automatically appended to my single output file. I have seen the **plyr** packaged being used. I am not sure if this is the best approach. Any suggestions please???

Comment: `x` is the only function parameter but I don't see any `x` in the body of the function. Plus it seems you use `subset` against the list of `filenames` in the second row.

Comment: Thanks Michele, that was a typo. 'filenames' should have been 'x'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this

```
for (file in filenames ) {
  ## do stuff
}
```

or this one

```
file.dir <- "/path/to/files"
for(infile in dir(file.dir, pattern="\\.txt$")) {
  ## do stuff
}
```

Comment: I have tried copying my function where you have **##do stuff** to no avail. When I put in the individual dataframe for example  `hyp(data1)` it works well. So I am wondering if there is a way to just list all the dataframes that I have read from the my individual files directly into the function hyp...ex  `hyp(data1,data2,data3)`

Comment: What errors are you getting? Maybe you need some debugging, so take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716152/why-do-r-objects-not-print-in-a-function-or-a-for-loop

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at the link. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood well what you want but if you call your files "file1", file"2", etc. :

```
for (j in 1:60)
{

    infile<-paste("C:/Users/dfs/Documents/Function/file",j,".txt",sep="")
    data<-read.table(infile,header=T,sep="\t")
}
```

is a way to make a  loop over your files.

You can then use something like :

```
output<-cbind(output,data)
```

(or rbind, or whatever you need to get the output you want) to get  the result in one single file.

Does that answer your question ?

Comment: Hello Vincent, I have spent the morning trying to work with your suggestion, but I keep getting the error:   
  **argument "subset" is missing, with no default**. However if I run the function hyp on the individual files everything works ok.

Comment: Sorry Vincent, I cleared the console and didn't save the command. However, I tried again, and a sample of 3 of my data file in my working dirrectry

Comment: Sorry Vincent, I cleared the console and didn't save the command. However, I tried again, and a sample of 3 of my data files in my working directory (actual filenames: file1,file2,file3). I then ran `for (j in 1:3)
+ {
+ 
+     infile<-paste("C:/Users/dfs/Documents/Function/file",j,".txt",sep="")
+     data<-read.table(infile,header=T,sep="\t")
+ }
` after which I used `hyp(data)`. Though the hyp-function did create an output, only data from one of the original data files was used (file1 I think). I also got this error `data.table 1.8.8  For help type: help("data.table")`.

Comment: Well I don't know the hyp function, from which package does it come ? I just ran :
`output<-data.frame()
    for (j in 1:60)
    {
        infile<-paste("C:/Documents and Settings/VBON/Mes documents/Donnees/Feuilles/patient",j,".csv",sep="")
    data<-read.table(infile,header=T,sep=";")

        output<-rbind(output,data$T2)
    }`

And it worked well... Are you sure you named your files the proper way ?

Comment: The hyp function is "my" function I created to pre-process my data (above in the original question). Yes I named my files the proper way (file1, file2 and file3). I run the code the way you gave it above, and the output file is empty. Question: should the line  `output<-data.frame()` be on separate line? And if I understand the code correctly, I will end up with a single file which merges all the input data files I have read. I would however like the files not merged into a single file, but remain as individual R objects.

Comment: Well they're merged if you use 'rbind()' but you don't have to, it was just an example. However, could you please run the same code as me just changing the infile to see if it works ? It will help finding where the error is.