# R: Using for-loop and filter data.table

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I'm trying to loop through a list which is used to subset a data.table and run the results through few lines of code. Subseting with a variable is working perfectly without the for loop but when the loop is included it does not work as expected. I guess the problem is either caused by data type or scope.

The following code works perfectly:

```
dt <- data.table(mpg)
list <- levels(dt$manufacturer)

dt[manufacturer==list[3]]
```

If I then try to loop through the list with a for loop: [updated code - **solved**]

```
for (var in list) {
  subs <- data.table(melt(dt[manufacturer==var, list(model, hwy, cty)], id.vars='model'))

  png(paste(var, 'png', sep='.'))
  print(ggplot(subs, aes(model, value, col=variable)) + geom_point())
  dev.off()
}
```

I do not get anything.

For me the code parts look identical and should work equally. Does anyone have a suggestion what might cause that I do not get anything with the second filtering ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It'd be much helpful if you elaborate on your end goal. What is it you want to do? Is your final task just to `print` each subset?

Comment: I would think my example is thorough enough as I want to subset using data table but not to use _apply or other methods - if that is what you are after. When I have subsetted the table I print a graph using the result. As there are numerous subsetting, like all the manufacturers of the mpg dataset, I though looping would be the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: IIUC, the idiomatic way then would be to do `dt[, <plotting function> , by=manufacturer]`

Comment: This quite good suggestion, but how would it work if I'm going to export the picture ? The reason I'm looping is because I have several lines following the subseting like melt, png and ggplot. Am I to understand you in that way that the variable var in my example can't be used to subset dt ? In my code everything works fine if I loop through list manually i.e. var <- list[i] where I change i myself.

Comment: your function in `j` should take care of writing the plots to a file. You could use `.SD` (or just the relevant columns directly) to pass the data in to the function. This is why it's important to explain what your complete task is. It would save the time for us to exchange here under comments and directly provide an answer.

Comment: Have updated the code to include the missing part. It is exactly because of j I'm looping, to use j as the plot name in a file. Unfortunately the problem is subseting the data set using j. I could as easily say why are you insisting on getting the rest of the code when I'm trying to ask if anybody knows why var does not work inside the for, more than getting a work around.

Comment: Looking at your code, the reason you don't get any output is precisely the reason @tonytonov has illustrated. Wrap around with `print` if you want to get an output within the loop.  I hope you get around to understanding the answer already here. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very common question. Check the difference:

```
for (i in 1:5) {i}
# no output
for (i in 1:5) {print(i)}
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
```

However, the code is executed:

```
for (i in 1:5) {j <- i^2}
j
[1] 25
```

Just use a global variable to store results in if you are running some code in a loop.

**UPD:**

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716152/why-do-r-objects-not-print-in-a-function-or-a-for-loop) discussion:

*In a loop, automatic printing is turned off, as it is inside a function. You need to explicitly print something in both cases if you want to see the output.*

The absence of printing is just a convention, which is preventing your console from being occasionally spammed.

Comment: I must admit I'm not getting the solution in your suggestion. Could you give an example using the code I provided ?

Comment: Check out Arun's comment above. What code are you running in a loop?

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly what my example is trying to do, get a subset of mpg with each manufacturer having its own subset. Then I'm graphing columns of the subset and export the graph, per manufacturer.

Comment: I have now updated my code so that it works. Print around the output line made the difference. Could you elaborate on why print is necessary as it is does not make any sense for me that it has to be there ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to loop through the manufacturers and run some summary code, try this:

```
#e.g. unique models per manufacturer
dt[,unique(model),by="manufacturer"]

#or with dplyr (same result)

require(dplyr)
dt %.% group_by(manufacturer) %.% summarise(unique(model))

   manufacturer          unique(model)
1          audi                     a4
2          audi             a4 quattro
3          audi             a6 quattro
4     chevrolet     c1500 suburban 2wd
5     chevrolet               corvette
6     chevrolet        k1500 tahoe 4wd
7     chevrolet                 malibu
8         dodge            caravan 2wd
9         dodge      dakota pickup 4wd
10        dodge            durango 4wd
11        dodge    ram 1500 pickup 4wd
12         ford         expedition 2wd
13         ford           explorer 4wd
14         ford        f150 pickup 4wd
15         ford                mustang
16        honda                  civic
17      hyundai                 sonata
18      hyundai                tiburon
19         jeep     grand cherokee 4wd
20   land rover            range rover
21      lincoln          navigator 2wd
22      mercury        mountaineer 4wd
23       nissan                 altima
24       nissan                 maxima
25       nissan         pathfinder 4wd
26      pontiac             grand prix
27       subaru           forester awd
28       subaru            impreza awd
29       toyota            4runner 4wd
30       toyota                  camry
31       toyota           camry solara
32       toyota                corolla
33       toyota land cruiser wagon 4wd
34       toyota      toyota tacoma 4wd
35   volkswagen                    gti
36   volkswagen                  jetta
37   volkswagen             new beetle
38   volkswagen                 passat
```