# R data.table within for loop runs very slow

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, data.table, time-series

I have 100,000 users each with a time series of about 1,000 time series values that I would like to calculate metrics for. Unfortunately my existing code runs very slow, I believe mainly due to the looping operation and not fully leveraging data.table.

I found a solution to an similar problem [R: Using for-loop and filter data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234243/r-using-for-loop-and-filter-data-table), but I am unsure of how I would be able to apply it to my task, which is a much more advanced statistics/time series problem. My objective is to be able to run N calculations for each user rather than just the 3 I am doing below (a, b, and c). I fear my current approach won't scale well.

The current code takes about 32 minutes to run for 10,000 people. When I removed the na.omit and ordering I did not see any reductions in speed either.

**Update: Please see details for "data" and "x".**

- Data represents all customer data history (daily demand)
- x is the list of customers of interest.

```
names(data) = c('id' 'demand' 'service_date');
names(x) = c('id')


    m = 100000
    h = data.frame(matrix(NA,m,8))
    names(h) = c("id", "u", "m1", "m2", "m3", "m3_m1", "m3_m2", "m2_m1")

    system.time(
    for (i in 1:m){

    dt = data.table(na.omit(data[data$id == x$id[i],]))
    dt = dt[order(service_date)]$demand

    u = floor(length(dt)/3);
    a = median((dt[1:u])); b = median(dt[(u+1):(2*u)]) ; c = median(dt[(2*u+1):(3*u)])

    h[i,] = data.frame(x$id[i],u,a,b,c,c-b,c-a,b-a)
    })
```

Comment: why do you need a loop for this.  Can't you group by 'id' and do this? Using the `==` to subset should decrease the speed

Comment: Hi akrun, yes good point. I am not sure I need a for loop, it is the only way I knew how to build it. My question is around how to speed up the code. Indeed, if i can bypass the for loop that would be excellent but I don't know how to given all the complicated stuff with the time series calculations. Simplest and fastest method would be best.

Comment: Who are `data` and `x`? Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

(This only does binary splits):

```
x_dt = data.table(x); data_dt = na.omit(data)
setkey(x_dt,id); setkey(data_dt,id) ;

system.time(data_dt <- data_dt[x_dt][order(id,service_date),])

system.time(x2 <- data_dt[,.(lt = length(demand),md = median(demand)),
           by =.(id, m = service_date < service_date[length(service_date)/2])])
```