# NAs introduced by coercion warning, and results of if block not printing

Tags: r

When I try to run only one if statement,for ex. if(outcome=="heart attack") I get a warning message : NAs introduced by coercion followed by the correct output. However , when I try to run the entire code listed below I get the warning message but not the output. So why is this happening? I have checked the code several times and don't see any mistakes.

```
setwd("C:/users/abhinav/Downloads/rprog_data_specdata")
best <- function(state,outcome){

 x <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 g<- vector()
 g<- unique(x$State)
 h<- c("heart attack","heart failure","pneumonia")
  if(any(g==state)==FALSE){
    stop("invalid state")
  }
  if(any(h==outcome)==FALSE){
    stop("invalid outcome")
  }
 if(outcome=="heart attack"){
   x <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   y<- as.numeric(x[which(x$State== state),11])
   z<-min(y,na.rm=TRUE)
   a<- x[which(x[[11]]==z),2]
   b<-sort(a)
   b[1]
 }

 if(outcome=="heart failure"){
   x <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   y<- as.numeric(x[which(x$State== state),17])
   z<-min(y,na.rm=TRUE)
   a<- x[which(x[[17]]==z),2]
   b<-sort(a)
   b[1]
 }
 if(outcome=="pneumonia"){
   x <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   y<- as.numeric(x[which(x$State== state),23])
   z<-min(y,na.rm=TRUE)
   a<- x[which(x[[23]]==z),2]
   b<-sort(a)
   b[1]
 }

}
```

Comment: For string comparisons, better to use `%in%` rather than `==`. For example `outcome %in% "pneumonia"`.

Comment: @Pascal That advice is just plain wrong.  You would use `%in%` to test against multiple conditions, for example, `outcome %in% c("heart attack", "pneumonia")`.  To test against a single value, `==` is both clearer in intent and faster to run.

Comment: @RichieCotton In what is it wrong?

Comment: @Pascal `outcome %in% "pneumonia"` is less readable and slower than `outcome == "pneumonia"`.  Read my previous comment for the case when you would use `%in%`.

Comment: It gives `TRUE` for `outcome <- "pneumonia"`.

Comment: @Pascal Let's try R public chat instead http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public

Answer (score 0):

The warning comes from trying to coerce character vectors that don't contain numbers to `numeric`.  You can reproduce it with, e.g.,

```
as.numeric("abc")
```

Your code is assigning values but not printing them.  Try changing `b[1]` to `print(b[1])`.  Also, read

[Why do R objects not print in a function or a "for" loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4716152/134830)

(What's true for for loops is true for if blocks too.)

---

There are some pretty awful violations of the [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself) rule here.  For example, the dataset is always read in twice, for no reason.  And the `sort` is called in the same way in every `if` block.  Try refactoring the code so that each `if` block is a call to a function.