# For loop not printing in R

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe` called `perceptionAvailInfo` which contains the below columns I hope to iterate through->

```
names(perceptionAvailInfo)
##  [1] "email"          "HomeAddress"    "HomePhone"      "Cellphone"     
##  [5] "Employer"       "PoliticalAffln" "WrittenWorks"   "Photo"         
##  [9] "Video"          "Groups"         "Birthdate"      "sex"           
## [13] "age"            "employ"
```

My code is as below ->

```
for (i in names(perceptionAvailInfo)) {
  perceptionAvailInfo[i]
}
```

I have tried printing just `i`,`perceptionAvailInfo` etc inside the for loop but I don't see any output for the forloop. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to insert `print` or `cat` in your `for` loop.

Comment: Also, read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4716380/3710546) for a complete overview.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
for (i in names(perceptionAvailInfo)) {
  print(i)
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I see the following error =>   Error in print[i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted

Comment: @RitheshShenthar  It is because `print` is a function and `[` is used for indexing. You cannot index a function. You need either `print(i)` or `print(perceptionAvailInfo[i])`.

Comment: Used print(i) instead of print[i] and it worked! I also saw the post marked by Pascal and it was helpful.