# Plot inside a loop using highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts

I am using highcharter for my graphs. I have different courses, which I need to draw same graphs for all. I am trying to have a for loop over courses and plot these graphs inside my loop.
The problem that it doesnt plot anything inside the loop and it works fine from outside the loop.

```
for(i in unique(my_data$CourseID)){
  courseData<-subset(my_data, my_data$CourseID== i)

  #Course by Majer
  byMajer <- table(courseData$MajerName)
  #barplot(byMajer, main="Students by Majer", xlab="Majers") 

  byM <- aggregate(courseData$MajerName, by=list(courseData$MajerName), FUN=length)

  hc <- highchart(debug = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_title(text = courseData$CourseName[1]) %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = byM$Group.1) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = byM$x)

  #this is not working. it shows nothing.
  hc

  #but if I try to have this, it works, I will use below variables outside the loop
  assign(paste("hc",i,sep=""), hc)
}

#Below graphs showing in the output. I need to get rid of them and use the one inside the loop.
hc1; hc2; hc3; hc4; hc5; hc6; hc7; hc8; hc9; hc10; hc11; hc12; hc13; hc14; hc15; hc16; hc17; hc18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to the problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716380/4046096

In short: Automatic printing is turned off in a loop, so you need to explicitly `print` something.

**Instead of `hc` use `print(hc)`.**

I do not have your data, but this code works fine:

```
for(i in c(1,2,3,4,5)){
  hc <- highchart(debug = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = list(1, i, i * 2, 5))

  print(hc)
}
```

Comment: @shanyour If this answer answers your question you could mark it as accepted - if not, please provide more info about what is left unanswered.