# Markdown R: Using highcharter to plot in a loop

Tags: r

I'm having some troubles with the idea of plotting various plots through a loop using the **highcharter library**. My code looks like this:

Here I upload the file and transform all NA values to "na" string.

````
DT <- fread(file, sep='auto',na.strings=c("Na","-",""), blank.lines.skip=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DTT <- DT
```

```{r, echo=F, results='asis'}
for(i in seq_along(DTT)) {
  DTT[[i]] <- sapply(DTT[[i]], function(x) if(is.na(x)) x <- "na" else x <- x)
  DTT[[i]] <- as.factor(DTT[[i]])
}
````

I tried to do a loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(DTT)) {

      hc <- highchart() %>%
        hc_title(text = 'prueba',
                 style = list(fontSize = "15px")) %>% 
        hc_chart(type = 'pie') %>% 
        hc_xAxis(categories = DTT[[i]]) %>% 
        hc_add_series(DTT[[i]], name = "Market", showInLegend = FALSE)
        hc
    }
```

Also I tried to make a function and call it through a loop but both didn't work.

Finally, I used a `lapply function` applying plot function to all columns of dataframe, but it didn't work as well. Perhaps i'm not doing the process of lapply correctly.

```
gethc <- function(DT) {
  hc <- highchart() %>%
    hc_title(text = 'prueba',
             style = list(fontSize = "15px")) %>% 
    hc_chart(type = 'pie') %>% 
    hc_xAxis(categories = DT) %>% 
    hc_add_series(DT, name = "Market", showInLegend = FALSE)
    hc
}

lapply(DTT, gethc)
```

Searching I found: [Plot inside a loop using highcharter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915969/plot-inside-a-loop-using-highcharter)

Where you have to use print inside the loop because automatic printing is turned off, but it didn't print anything.

**Example:**

```
DT <- mtcars
for(i in seq_along(DT)) {
  DT[[i]] <- sapply(DT[[i]], function(x) if(is.na(x)) x <- "na" else x <- x)
}

gethc <- function(i) {
  hc <- highchart() %>%
    hc_title(text = 'prueba',
             style = list(fontSize = "15px")) %>% 
    hc_chart(type = 'pie') %>% 
    hc_xAxis(categories = DT[[i]]) %>% 
    hc_add_series(DT[[i]], name = "Market", showInLegend = FALSE)
    print(hc)
}

for(i in seq_along(DT)) {
  gethc(i)
}
```

This works in .R program but not in an R Markdown

It will be really helpful if someone have some solution for this problem.

Comment: So using `print(hc)` instead of `hc` does not work? Can you give us a working reproducible example? Are you trying to create many plots? Because you are overwriting `hc` each time. Does it work outside of your (presumably) RMarkdown document (i.e. in a normal clean session)?

Comment: Yes it works in normal .R  and it plots perfectly but in markdown it's not working at all, if you want I can send you the code.

Comment: Your question is much more likely to receive an answer if you include a simply fully reproducible example.

Comment: I added an Example the first for loop is optional, it only looks for empty values and adds a string "na" to them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like in R MarkDown there is no way to print highcharter charts using a loop, but I found a way using **htmltools** and creating a list of highcharter  charts to send them to a `tagList` and luckily now prints everything correctly.

```
DT <- mtcars
gethc <- function(i) {
  hc <- highchart() %>%
    hc_title(text = 'prueba',
             style = list(fontSize = "15px")) %>% 
    hc_chart(type = 'pie') %>% 
    hc_xAxis(categories = DT[[i]]) %>% 
    hc_add_series(DT[[i]], name = "Market", showInLegend = FALSE)
    hc
}
a = list()
for(i in seq_along(DT)) {
  a[[i]] <- gethc(i)

}

htmltools::tagList(a)
```