# R console output missing from nested if

Tags: r, if-statement, output

Context: I'm running some very big generalized additive models using mgcv. To avoid unnecessary recomputation and allow reproducibility I save the models to disk. Usually several models need to be fitted, a first one to extract autocorrelation (file1) and then a second one correcting for autocorrelation (file2). Below is a minimal example of my code.

```
if (!file.exists('file2')) {
  if (!file.exists('file1')) {
    writeLines('computing file 1')
    1+1
  }
  writeLines('computing file 2')
  1+1
}
```

which gives the following output

```
computing file 1
computing file 2
[1] 2
```

I noticed that some output of the inner if is missing, although writeLines, model computation and model saving happens, there is some diagnostic information which does not show up in the console/log file, much like the result of the 1+1 which does not show up.
I tried rearranging the {} brackets onto single lines, and also to put sink(logfile.txt) [code] sink() around it, but that did not change anything. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by `result of 1+1 which does not show up`? Where do expect `1+1` to show up?

Comment: I would expect the output of 1+1 to appear between computing file 1 and computing file 2

Comment: We all understand that result of inner `1+1` will not show up as that is not last line that is executed. Only the last `1+1` will appear.

Comment: Use `print(1+i)`

Comment: How so? Even if I outcomment the second 1+1 the first one does not appear. Shouldn't all output that occurs within these ifs find their way to the console/log file?

Comment: Using print() as suggested by G5W seems to do the job. But why does this not find its way to the console/log in the first place?

Comment: Some related information available at [Why do R objects not print in a function or a “for” loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4716152/4752675)

Comment: Been working with R for quite a while, but wasn't aware of that! Thanks a lot G5W!

Comment: My initial concern was that I may miss warnings from the model fitting (e.g. when the model did not converge). The solution should be to add print(warnings()) to the inner loop then.