# Printing For Loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, psych

I am looking to build a forloop for some factor analysis in R, and save the outputs each time. I have the following code:

```
library(psych)
for (i in 5:10){
fit[i] <- principal(data, nfactors=i, rotate="varimax")
fit[i]}
```

What coud I do to gain the outputs of each iteration?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Create `fit <- vector("list", 6); for(i in seq_along(5:10)){ fit[[i]] <- `

Comment: Use apply, and result will be a list: `res <- lapply(5:10, function(i){principal(data, nfactors=i, rotate="varimax")})`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print(i); flush.console()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717453/680068)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @zx8754 `
  res <- lapply(5:10, function(i){principal(data, nfactors=i, rotate="varimax")})` This gives an error of Error in UseMethod("isSymmetric") : 
  no applicable method for 'isSymmetric' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: No, drop the for loop completely. Either use my lapply solution or akrun's forloop.

Comment: Are you trying to get print out from the forloop? If so, see linked post about `flush.console`.

Comment: @zx8754 Taking the forloop out leaves the same error of 'isSymmetric', I am just trying to find the best way to write this to a dataset

Comment: According to manual `principal` returns a list. So if you use lapply solution then you would have a list of lists output.