# What's the use of this for loop final argument on R?

Tags: r

I can't figure out the use for that last "output" argument. "output" is an empty vector created to put the data created by the function (i).

```
output[1] <- Count[Year == max(Year)]
outmat <- sapply(1:sims, function(i) {
  for (t in 1:years) output[t + 1] <- output[t] * sim.RM[t, i]
  output ## I have no idea why is this one necessary, and it just doesnt work without it
})
```

Comment: This is a implicit return (the last calculated value before the end of the function). If you want you can do it explicit: `return(output)`. The expression `output` is not part of the `for`-loop.

Comment: For [added context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716152/why-do-r-objects-not-print-in-a-function-or-a-for-loop), without any return the loop just runs without writing any of the output that was contained within the function.

Comment: Thank you very much to you both.