# Printing 'Hello world' n number of times in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to teach myself R and am experimenting with `for` loops, a basic construct in any imperative language.

At first, I used a for loop to increment a variable an arbitrary number of times:

```
x = 0
for (i in 1:1000) {
    x = x + 1
}
```

This works as expected. However, when I attempted to `paste` a simple message in this loop, I get no output. Specifically:

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
    paste('Hello world!')
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: `paste` is for concatenating strings, use `print`

Comment: Why does `paste` work outside of the loop then?

Comment: The command `"Hello world!"` will also give you the same result -- it's ultimately calling the print method. It never makes sense to call `paste` with a single argument.

Comment: Loops are generally avoided in `R`. Use the `apply` family of functions, or `map` in `dplyr`.

Comment: Thanks @hmhensen. I'm new to R and am still unfamiliar with the conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R you need to use print inside loops to get the output:

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
    print(paste('Hello world!'))
}
```

Best!

Comment: Thanks! Does this apply to all blocks like functions and if statements?

Comment: You don't really need to keep the `paste()` in the loop, just `print()` will do it.

Comment: HI! Functions are not verbose (although the parameter returned is printed if not assigned to a variable). On the other hand If statements are verbose. Here is a very interesting thread about for loops: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716152/why-do-r-objects-not-print-in-a-function-or-a-for-loop and here to show progress in those loops https://medium.com/human-in-a-machine-world/displaying-progress-in-a-loop-or-function-r-664796782c24. I hope you enjoy learning R!

Answer (score 0):

Or use the `apply` family! 
like this for instance:

```
sapply(rep(1,100),FUN = function(x) print("hello world!"))
```