# R interate over files and write results

Tags: r

Making my first attempt in R to iterate over data files to do an analysis and write output to a file.  Here is the code I have:

```
# load packages igraph, dils, sna
sink('analysis-output.txt')
for (week in c("002","003","004","005","006")) {
    cat("*** ",week,"\n")
    obs <- read.table(paste(week,"obs.txt",sep="-"),sep="\t", header=FALSE)
    per <- read.table(paste(week,"per.txt",sep="-"),sep="\t", header=FALSE)
    n <- length(obs)
    mper <- AdjacencyFromEdgelist(per, check.full = TRUE)
    mobs <- AdjacencyFromEdgelist(obs, check.full = TRUE)
    g<-array(c(mper[[1]],mobs[[1]]),c(n,n,2))
    q<-qaptest(g,gcor,g1=1,g2=2)
    summary(q)
}
sink()
```

When I run this, there are no errors, but analysis-output.txt contains only the output of the cat function, i.e.

```
***  002 
***  003 
***  004 
***  005 
***  006
```

However, when I run the code interior to the loop by itself like so

```
sink('analysis-output.txt')
week = "002"
cat("*** ",week,"\n")
obs <- read.table(paste(week,"obs.txt",sep="-"),sep="\t", header=FALSE)
per <- read.table(paste(week,"per.txt",sep="-"),sep="\t", header=FALSE)
n <- length(obs)
mper <- AdjacencyFromEdgelist(per, check.full = TRUE)
mobs <- AdjacencyFromEdgelist(obs, check.full = TRUE)
g<-array(c(mper[[1]],mobs[[1]]),c(n,n,2))
q<-qaptest(g,gcor,g1=1,g2=2)
summary(q)
sink()
```

I do get the summary results in the output file:

```
***  002 

QAP Test Results

Estimated p-values:
    p(f(perm) >= f(d)): 0.355 
    p(f(perm) <= f(d)): 0.656 

Test Diagnostics:
    Test Value (f(d)): -0.09045692 
    Replications: 1000 
    Distribution Summary:
        Min:     -0.207416 
        1stQ:    -0.1971768 
        Med:     -0.1720356 
        Mean:    0.01895663 
        3rdQ:    0.1185298 
        Max:     0.9982945
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do R objects not print in a function or a "for" loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716152/why-do-r-objects-not-print-in-a-function-or-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sink` diverts the console output to a file, so the data needs to be output by R to appear in the file. I think what's missing is that, within a loop, you need to explicitly `print` the output of `summary` to get it to appear in the console (and thus be written by sink).

Compare the console output of these two loops:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
    print(summary(cars))
}
```

Prints results to console

```
for (i in 1:5) {
    summary(cars)
}
```

Does not print to console

Comment: You are right.  Thanks.  Any idea why the summary() prints to console when not in a loop but requires the print() wrapper when inside a loop?

Comment: @Steve Apparently, automatic printing is turned off in a for loop (probably to prevent clogging up the console with undesired messages) so you need to explicitly print things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716152/why-do-r-objects-not-print-in-a-function-or-a-for-loop