# How to print the first six values of a list of data frames

Tags: r

I was trying out this code. I want to print the first six values of both the dataframes. But this isn't working. Where am I going wrong?

```
d1 = mtcars
d2 = Arthritis
d = list(d1,d2)
for(i in 1:2)
{
  head(d[[i]])
  }
```

I tried it without the for loop and it works. I mean if I put in head(d[[1]])  I get the first six values of mtcars. But with the loop it is not printing anything

Comment: Enclose `head(d[[i]])` inside the the `print( )` function.

Comment: or `lapply(d, head)` and no need to call `print()`

Answer (score 0):

Automatic printing is turned off inside loops and functions (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716380/1034677)). To print inside of a loop or function, explicitly call the `print()` function.

```r
d1 <- mtcars
d2 <- data(iris)
d  <- list(d1,d2)
for(i in 1:2) {
  print(head(d[[i]]))
}
```