# R print confusion matrix in each iteration within for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, printing, classification

Is it possible to print a confusion matrix using a `SDMTools`'s method `confusion.matrix()` each time within a for loop. Here is some pseudo-code:

```
for (wei_vec in weight_vector) {
    classifier <- rpart(y~., train_data, weights=wei_vec, method='class')
    prediction <- predict(classifier, test_data)
    confusion.matrix(test_data$output, prediction, .5)
}
```

Unfortunately similiar code does NOT print the error matrix each iteration. Shame because it could be useful for examining different parameters as shown in foo-example above. The matrix is printed normally when `confusion.matrix(test_data$output, prediction, .5)` is called in open-code.

Do anyone know if the iterative printing with this method is possible?

Thank you for any suggestions,

Max

Comment: What errors are you getting? It's hard to help when you don't provide a reproducible example. I see a few potential problems. First, you call you model `classifier`, then refer to it as `model` in the next line. Second, `wei_vec` should be a vector of same length as observations in your training data, and it looks problematic. Finally, `predict` for objects of class `rpart` returns a matrix, not a vector as is expected in confusion.matrix. I think one or all of these problems is affecting your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing of objects isn't automatic within for loops, and must be explicitly called using `print()`.

See more here: [Why do R objects not print in a function or a "for" loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716152/why-do-r-objects-not-print-in-a-function-or-a-for-loop)

Comment: Yeah, that was the case. I thought that method had print built-in. Thanks for help.