# How to loop and print all links rselenium

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to print all links inside a webpage in rselenium using a for loop. I can print just a specific value without using a for loop, but when using it, the result is nothing.

```
els <- con$findElements(using = "tag name", "a")
  for(val in length(els)){
     elem <- els[[val]]
     class(elem)
     elem$getElementText()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a loop, automatic printing is turned off, as it is inside a function. You need to include print inside the loop. Try:

```
els <- con$findElements(using = "tag name", "a")
for(val in length(els)){
     elem <- els[[val]]
     class(elem)
     print(elem$getElementText())
 }
```

Answered before:
[Why do R objects not print in a function or a "for" loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716152/why-do-r-objects-not-print-in-a-function-or-a-for-loop)