# save html files on a loop with tab_model on sjPlot in R

Tags: r

In a certain loop I am trying to use tab_model and save with it all the outcomes:

```
keys<-c("a","b","c")

for (i in keys) {
  formula <- as.formula(paste0("int", "~","int2", "+","int3"))
  x2 <- lme(formula, data = df, random = ~ 1 | int4, na.action = na.omit)
  tab_model(x2, file = paste0('name_', i,"_toshow.html"))
}
```

When I do that it runs and do not download the files
(it works fine when I don't do that in a loop)

Comment: it works fine when I don't do that in a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took some sample data from the [documentation](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/tab_model_estimates.html) of the function. It's easier / faster to help if you provide some dummy data / a reproducible example!

```
# load package
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
library(sjlabelled)

# sample data
data("efc")
efc <- as_factor(efc, c161sex, c172code)

# sample regression
m1 <- lm(barthtot ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)

# try
for (i in 1:3) {
  print(tab_model(m1, file = paste0("test_",i,".html")))
}
```

It works when you put `print()` around the `tab_model()` function. This is because in loops, outputs are not automatically printed out. See here: [Why do R objects not print in a function or a "for" loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716152/why-do-r-objects-not-print-in-a-function-or-a-for-loop). Since the functions seems to be depending on printing the output before saving it, you have to "manually" print it.

Comment: Great, Thank you!