# Why does sprintf not work inside a for loop? A bug in R?

Tags: r

Minimal working example ("test.R"):

```
i=1
sprintf("Hello world %s.\n\n",i)

for(i in 2:3) {
  sprintf("Hello world %s.\n\n",i)
}
```

What this **should** do:

```
[1] "Hello world 1.\n\n" 
[1] "Hello world 2.\n\n" 
[1] "Hello world 3.\n\n"
```

What it actually does:

```
[1] "Hello world 1.\n\n"
```

**Is this a bug in the language R?**

Comment: Use `print(sprintf("Hello world %s.\n\n",i))`.

Comment: Why you claim that your code **should** do what you expect? Is that documented somewhere? For printing, use `print`. FWIW, your loop does not print anything.

Comment: ``for(i in 2:3) {print(sprintf("Hello world %s.\n\n",i))}`` works

Comment: You _should_ also use `%d` for an `integer` here.  R helps you, but you risk forming a habit that may not work with other `sprintf()` implementations in other languages, if you ever use them.

Answer (score 2):

You must wrap whatever you want printing in `print`, as R objects don't automatically print to console within the loop.

```
for(i in 2:3) {
  print(sprintf("Hello world %s.\n\n",i))
}
```

Returns:

```
[1] "Hello world 2.\n\n"
[1] "Hello world 3.\n\n"
```

You could find some more info in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716152/why-do-r-objects-not-print-in-a-function-or-a-for-loop).